# How to collapse function body in Visual Studio 2010 editor?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

I am new to Visual Studio 2010 and I am missing one Notepad++ feature, that is collapsing...

Where do I anable such option in Visual Studio and Resharper?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this and let me know what you think. http://jsoutlining.codeplex.com/ This Visual Studio Addon will let you expand and collapse css- and javascript files just as you can do with regular .cs (or .vb)-files.

Answer (score 6):

Ctrl+M,Ctrl+O to collapse function body

Answer (score 0):

At least for .css files:
You can add outlining glyphs wherever you want by:

- Select some rows (which should be outlined) and then
- Press Ctrl+M, Ctrl+H.

Now you have the outlining glyph. You can close the file and reopen it - the outlining glyphs remain.

Answer (score 0):

There is no expand/collapse outline option available in visual studio for CSS files.

With some files, such as C# / VB class files, you can outline code using 'regions' or automatically by setting it in Tools -> Options -> TextEditor -> **your language** -> Formatting, but this is not included for CSS.

All the best

Answer (score 0):

I would be recommend **Web Essentials** extension [[http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6ed4c78f-a23e-49ad-b5fd-369af0c2107f]](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6ed4c78f-a23e-49ad-b5fd-369af0c2107f).

Besides desired feature it provides great set of another ones.